# Name attribute in ace editor

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I want to set the name attribute to an ace editor. After inspecting elements, I found that the ace textarea has a class of `ace_text-input`. Since I can't edit it directly, I tried something like this in JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector(".ace_text-input").name = 'code_content';
```

But it gives me this error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of null.**
Does anybody know what to do?

Comment: When is this code executed?  This element is probably not in the DOM at that point.   You probably need to execute this line when the ACE editor has been initialized.  There's probably an event for that.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Oh, I get it, thank you!